# How to remove Win+K 'connect to wireless device' shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 10 there's a Win+K shortcut to launch the "Connect to a wireless display and audio devices" sidebar app. I would like to remove this shortcut because I like to use Win+K as a shortcut to launch an app using an AutoHotKey script that I use on multiple computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the shortcut in the AHK:

```
#k::msgbox Hello
```

It takes precedence over the built-in Windows shortcut. For me, the above works. (I am running AHK elevated, i.e. as administrator.)

Comment: This worked! According to https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm the 'LWin' and 'RWin' are the left and right windows keys. I missed that the # key can be the windows key.

Comment: Is there any built-in way such as registry or group policy to disable this without using autohotkey?